# Multiple Commands in one Line - Powershell, Escape "

Tags: powershell-4.0

I am trying to run multiple powershell commands in one line through Command Prompt by following command -

```
powershell -Command " $auth = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes('admin'+ ':' + 'admin')) ; Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://somehost:8080/xyz" -Method:Get -Headers @{"Authorization"="Basic $auth"; "Accept"="application/xml"} -ContentType "application/xml" "

However, i am receiving the following error -

Basic : The term 'Basic' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:253
+ ... {Authorization=Basic $auth; Accept=application/xml} -ContentType
application/xml
+                    ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Basic:String) [], CommandNotFou
   ndException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

The double quotes within the Invoke-WebRequest is creating the issue. I tried to escape using `, giving multiple double quotes and tried different combinations but in vain. Tried for 3 full days and finally coming here as the last resort. Kindly help in constructing the above. I have only access to CMD and need to execute powershell from there only. Hence, I need to use powershell -Command and should be followed by the above powershell commands.

Answer (score 0):

easiest way to work around weird sequences of characters is using [encoded command](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/timid/2014/03/26/powershell-encodedcommand-and-round-trips/):

```
$command = 'dir "c:\program files" '
$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($command)
$encodedCommand = [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
powershell.exe -encodedCommand $encodedCommand
```

you could combine that with the [format string](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) operator to create your desired string

Comment: This does not solve the purpose as I have to execute all commands in same line. When I do that, I cant execute the commands in sequence without using ". If i use the double quotes, it will clash with the existing quotes in the command and is throwing the error.

Comment: it does, you need to construct this encoded command and then pass that to your powershell.exe. so you construct encoded command outside of the cmd session. in your local powershell

Answer (score 0):

No Worries.. I got this worked finally -

```
powershell -Command  " $auth = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes('admin'+ ':' + 'admin')) ; " Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://someurl:8080/xyz' -method:get -Headers @{'Authorization'='Basic ' " + " $auth  " } ";
```